# Notify me if a dependency for my issue is resolved

Tags: jira

I'm using JIRA v6.2.7, where I can link two issues using relations like `is necessary for`, `blocks` and their respective counterparts. Let's say I have an issue A assigned to me and an issue B assigned to someone else, and B is necessary for A. Now, I would like to be notified if issue B is resolved so I can start working on A.

Is it possible to configure this in JIRA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility would be to make a JQL query, save it as a filter and then subscribe to this filter.

**1. JQL query**

The following query gets all issues that are assigned to me and had a dependency resolved in the last 24 hours:

```
assignee = currentUser() and (
    issueFunction in linkedIssuesOf("resolutiondate >=-24h", "is necessary for")
    or
    issueFunction in linkedIssuesOf("resolutiondate >=-24h", "blocks")
)
```

And this is the reverse query, it gets the corresponding issues that have been resolved and are therefor no longer blocking my work:

```
resolutiondate >=-24h and (
    issueFunction in linkedIssuesOf("assignee = currentUser()", "is dependent on")
    or
    issueFunction in linkedIssuesOf("assignee = currentUser()", "is blocked by")
)
```

**2. Save as Filter**

Copy one of the above queries into the search, hit enter to see if everything works, then press "Save as", name the filter and submit.

**3. Subscribe to Results**

After saving the filter, the "Details" link becomes available and there you can set up a subscription. For the above filter a daily e-mail makes sense. You can adjust the period, e.g. to a week, but make sure to keep the filter and subscription settings in sync. Otherwise you will either receive the same issue in various mails or miss some issues completely.

I found this solution while researching my question. If there is an easier way I'd like to learn about it!